# Rails polymorphic association overridden getter with eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I've got something with horrible design. It has kind-of-polymorphic association with overridden getter, e.g.

```
class Whtvr
  belongs_to :assoc, polymorphic: true

  def assoc
    if assoc_type == 'a_type'
      AType.find(assoc_id)
    else
      BaseType.find(assoc_id)
    end
  end
end
```

How can I make this eager-loadable?

```
Whtvr.includes(:assoc).find(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't eager load polymorphic associations I think, even if the getter wasn't overridden.

You would need to define a `belongs_to` for every type of association.

```
belongs_to :a_type, class_name: "AType", foreign_key: "assoc_id"

belongs_to :base_type, class_name: "BaseType", foreign_key: "assoc_id"
```

And then, use one of the other depending on what you wanna do.

```
Whtvr.includes(:a_type).find(1)
```

Comment: I believe that should be `Whtvr.includes(:a_type, :base_type).find(1)` with something like `def assoc; a_type || base_type; end`

Comment: I don't understand why you have to override the getter like that though.

Comment: So I can keep the old interface and surely get one of script if any.

Comment: seems like that worked for me, ty and gratz with 10k (: